# Implementation of nested Datagridview windows form c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

While implementing datagrid inside another, my scenario is

`Datagridview1` will hold columns `DepartmentID` & `DeptName`

There is also a column for buttonColumn `Expand` which `on_click` add a text column  `Employee` and in the `Employee` column respective `EmployeeId` and `Name` to be show which comes from `Datagridview2`

**Code is:**

`int count =0;`

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

        if (dataGridView1.Columns.Contains("Expand") && e.ColumnIndex == dataGridView1.Columns["Expand"].Index)
        {
            if (count % 2 == 0)//for even count show the datagrid2 else hide
            {
                var d = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].DataBoundItem as Test.Departments;

                dataGridView2.DataSource = Test.EmployeeDataaccessLayer.GetAllEmployeesByDepartment(d.DeptId);
                AddemployeeColumns();
               /* foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView2.Rows)
                {
                    int index = r.Index;
                    var dd = dataGridView2.Rows[index].DataBoundItem as Test.Employee;
                    dataGridView1["Employee", rowIndex].Value = dd;
                }*/ This part to be correct
                count++;
            }
            else 
            {
                dataGridView2.Visible = false;
                count++;
            }


    }
```

So i basically want to add the `DatagridView2` to the cell `Employee` which shows the employees details. It is easier in `Asp.net` where we bind the child grid but in windows form how to implement this?

Comment: I've never tried that myself, but maybe the link in the first reply to this MSDN question can give you some good pointers. This definitely looks like something you're going to have to implement yourself, or maybe look into commercial controls libraries such as Telerik or DevExpress.  Link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/38dc504b-5e5f-43ee-bdc7-045adc335ba5/nested-datagridview-in-windows-forms-using-c-datagridview-within-datagridview

Comment: Also this can help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.idatagridvieweditingcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It seems to me that the way to go here would be a custom cell/column type with a multi-column ComboBox.  That way you can do away with the second grid altogether.